# sql query, can exist LIKE and == Operators?

Tags: sql, database

i have a query but doesn't work
thanks.

```
query =  name=='Name' OR lstName== 'Lname' OR mddName == 'Mname' 
OR (name LIKE 'Name%' OR lstName LIKE 'Lname%' OR mddName LIKE'Mname%')
```

can mix this operators?

thanks

Comment: There is no `==` in SQL

Comment: I am using a framework xPO , that if there exists.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `==` operator in SQL. The equality test in SQL is simply `=`:

```
name ='Name' OR lstName = 'Lname' OR mddName = 'Mname' 
OR (name LIKE 'Name%' OR lstName LIKE 'Lname%' OR mddName LIKE 'Mname%')
```

Moreover, you should note that the `%` wildcard could represent an empty string, so your equality check is redundant, and just using your `like` conditions would suffice:

```
name LIKE 'Name%' OR lstName LIKE 'Lname%' OR mddName LIKE 'Mname%'
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are already doing `LIKE` queries as you are using `%` wildcard, so first part of your query is already covered in the second part when you are doing `LIKE`. you can just do:

```
query = name LIKE 'Name%' OR lstName LIKE 'Lname%' OR mddName LIKE'Mname%'
```

Moreover, there is no `==` operator in SQL. It is simply `=`, but you don't need it here, as above query will give you desired output.